# Python Tkinter removing disabled button overlay

Tags: python, python-2.7, button, tkinter, overlay

In my Program I use a picture in a button. If I now disable this button with `button.configure(state="disabled")`, I get a white overlay over the whole button. Can I remove this overlay? If yes how? Thanks in advance. Here is an example code:

```
import Tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()

def disable():
    button1.config(state="disabled")

button1=tk.Button(command=disable)
testbild=tk.PhotoImage(file="testbild.gif")
button1.image=testbild
button1.configure(relief="flat", image=testbild, height=180, width=180,
                         background="lightgreen", activebackground="lightgreen", bd=0)
button1.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: I think it's an unavoidable aspect of Tkinter.  Someone at this question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11366349/tkinter-color-of-disabled-buttons-disabled-optionmenus) suggested a workaround you might try.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using a button? If you want an image that doesn't do anything when the user clicks, just add the image to a Label. The disabled effect serves a purpose, alerting the user that they can't do what they expect to be able to do.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to change the color of the stipple by setting a background color at Button creation time:

```
button1=tk.Button(command=disable, bg='black')
```

Comment: Well, this don't really helps me. With this code I can the change the color of the overlay, but actually I want to completely remove the overlay.